# mySQL MULTIPLE ROWS DYNAMIC INSERT PYTHON

Tags: python, mysql, python-idle

My Objective is to add multiple rows of Data in the Table but I get an error everytime  , I tried multiple variations of the code and Sorry for not asking the question earlier , I didn't know how , I don't use much of Stack Overflow .

> The Updated Code is in the end .

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python/sqlconnector4.py", line 25, in <module>
    entry_table(number)
  File "G:/Python/sqlconnector4.py", line 17, in entry_table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME , ADDRESS ) VALUES (thelist.split("'',''"))")
  File "C:\Users\tushar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 559, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\tushar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 494, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\tushar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 396, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWqA.png)

```
import mysql.connector

my=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost' , user='root' , password='rootroot' , database='tushar')
c=my.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T1 (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)")
    my.commit()

def entry_table(n):
    thelist = []  
    for x in range(0,n) :
        user_name = input("ENTER NAME NUMBER {}: ".format(x+1))
        user_state = input("ENTER STATE {} LIVES IN : ".format(user_name))
        thelist.append(user_name)
        thelist.append(user_state)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME , ADDRESS ) VALUES (thelist.split("'',''"))")
        my.commit()
    for x in range(0,n) :
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM T1")

number = int(input("Enter The Number of Rows You want to Fill : "))

create_table()
entry_table(number)
```

import mysql.connector

my=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost' , user='root' , password='rootroot' , database='tushar')
c=my.cursor()

def create_table():

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T1 (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)")
my.commit()
```

def entry_table(n):

```
for x in range(0,n) :
    user_name = input("ENTER NAME NUMBER {}: ".format(x+1))
    user_state = input("ENTER STATE {} LIVES IN : ".format(user_name))
    c.execute("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME , ADDRESS ) VALUES ( ? , ?)", user_name , user_state )
    my.commit()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM T1")
myresult = c.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
      print(x)
```

number = int(input("Enter The Number of Rows You want to Fill : "))
create_table()
entry_table(number)
c.close()
my.close()

Comment: Nice code, but there is no question whatsoever, so I do not really know what you expect us to do.

Comment: I want to able to add multiple rows to the table in one go , I get an error with this code , I can't seem to make it work .

Comment: Consider adding error message to your question.

Comment: @TusharGuliany pls add the exact error message to the question and indicate the line of code here you receive the error message. Pls also provide the background to the problem, like what exactly you are trying to achieve and what the expected outcome should look like. I really don't understand how you expect us to help you without providing these basic information.

Comment: @Shadow I did , I updated the Post , Please Help Me . Thanks

Comment: basically , I am new to Python , I don't understand what this error message means .

Comment: You're trying to write python code within your SQL query. Not only that, but you're calling `split()` on a list. My best guess would be `c.execute("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME , ADDRESS ) VALUES (?, ?)", thelist)` but I can't be sure because presumably `thelist` keeps on growing and you'll end up with more values than binding parameters.

Comment: @roganjosh I tried what You said , It says :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python/sqlconnector4.py", line 25, in <module>
    entry_table(number)
  File "G:/Python/sqlconnector4.py", line 17, in entry_table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME , ADDRESS ) VALUES (?, ?)", thelist)
  File "C:\Users\tushar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: @khelwood , Okay , Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are passing the python syntax as a part of your sql statement and the commands don’t make sense. Many fixes, simplest one is that you don’t need the list

```
def entry_table(n):
    for x in range(0,n) :
        user_name = input("ENTER NAME NUMBER {}: ".format(x+1))
        user_state = input("ENTER STATE {} LIVES IN : ".format(user_name))
        data = (user_name, user_state)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO T1 (NAME , ADDRESS ) VALUES (%s, %s);", data)
        my.commit()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM T1")
    print(c.fetchall())
```

Some other things that are out of scope here but relevant:

1. The transaction could be committed after the loop since we are not accessing the data prior to it.
2. The cursor is never closed.
3. The connection is never closed.

Edit: Replaced `?,?` With`%s, %s` per 
[API Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: Hello Sir , Thank You for The Answer , It doesn't cause any errors now , but It still isn't working as it is supposed to , The Row isn't added to the Table . It takes the Input and that's It , It has no other Output on the Screen .

Comment: @TusharGuliany there won't  be any output on the screen because you don't use `fetchall()` to get the results of `c.execute("SELECT * FROM T1")`

Comment: Try the updated code based on the API docs for MySQL. What I have you earlier was not valid in MySQL it seems. And yes need to call fetchall. Also, that does not have to be in a loop. I am out and about so having a hard time formatting the answer on the phone. Will keep trying for a bit though. In the mean time you can check it in the database directly if you want.

Comment: It worked , Thanks , Seems like the error was the '?' . MySQL accepts either '%' method or format method but since format is not applicable because it needs to be replaced within the sql statement .
Thanks alot